# What are Compass and Sass and how do they differ?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I would like to start using Compass and Sass to speed up development. At the moment, I have installed Sass on a mac and instructed it to watch a Scss file for input, and a CSS file for generated output.

From many articles, Sass is used with Compass, I'm wondering why that is the case and just what does Compass add that Sass comes without? If you can give an example, the better.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

From *Sass and Compass in Action*, by Wynn Netherland, Nathan Weizenbaum, Chris Eppstein, and Brandon Mathis:

> #### 1.3 What is Compass?
>
> Compass helps Sass authors write smarter stylesheets and empowers a community
> of designers and developers to create and share powerful frameworks. Put simply,
> **Compass is a Sass framework**, designed to make the work of styling the web
> smooth and efficient. Much like Rails as a web application framework for Ruby,
> **Compass is a collection of helpful tools and battle-tested best practices for Sass**.

(emphasis added)

Comment: this answer is quite bookish. Usage Examples is required.

Answer (score 70):

Compass is an extension of Sass (as in Compass requires Sass).  It has its own compiler (instead of `sass --watch`, you use `compass watch`).  It has a large collection of mixins and functions that you'll find incredibly useful (while commonly pointed to for generating vendor prefixed CSS3 properties, it can do things like automatically generate spritemaps and the CSS to go with them).

Compass is also built in such a way that you can bundle your own *bootstrap* type library for easily deploying in multiple projects without the need to copy/paste the source for it in each one.

Comment: Is it a library built on SASS, or is it a a new language (possibly backwards compatible extension) of SASS?

Comment: Ciro: The it's more the first thing, but it's not really a library. It includes a library of mixins and functions, but it's more than that, as it has its own compiler as well.